# Disable autocomplete on Vuetify v-text-field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify's v-text-field, and I want to disable autocomplete. I have `autocomplete="false"`, which is the correct syntax as I have seen online, but I still get autocomplete suggestions. Any suggestions?

```
<v-text-field
 outlined
 placeholder="Search"
 autocomplete="false"
 v-model="searchBar"
 @input="search()"
 :hint="searchResults.length + ' ' + this.searchResultTag + ' found'"
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Please try `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use autocomplete="off" in `v-text-field`:

```
<v-text-field
   autocomplete="off"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

autocomplete="null" worked for me in `v-text-field`
(but autocomplete="off" didnt...)

```
<v-text-field
  autocomplete="null"
/>
```